# MySQL COUNT() or SUM()?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a doubt for use count and sum. Here I get just what I want with this query, why in the guides say use COUNT instead SUM?

```
+----+------------+-------+------+
| id | dateinsert | name  | stat |
+----+------------+-------+------+
|  1 | 2019-12-01 | john  |   17 |
|  2 | 2019-12-01 | peter |   19 |
|  3 | 2019-12-01 | jane  |   17 |
|  4 | 2019-12-02 | phil  |   19 |
|  5 | 2019-12-02 | jane  |   17 |
|  6 | 2019-12-02 | phil  |   19 |
+----+------------+-------+------+


SELECT
SUM(stat=17)+SUM(stat=19) AS first_status,
FROM my_table
WHERE dateinsert >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY datainsert


+------------+--------------+
| datainsert | first_status |
+------------+--------------+
| 01/12/2019 |            3 |
| 02/12/2019 |            3 |
+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: The count of 1,0,1,0,1 is 5. The sum of 1,0,1,0,1 is 3.

Comment: @cloude  `count()` will count the no. of rows whereas `sum()` will add the values

Comment: Your SQL has syntax issues.

Comment: @Booboo where are issues?

Comment: You have a comma (`,`) after `first_status`. You should also `select dateinsert` in order to be displaying that column. So what you are displaying does not match up with your actual SQL.

Comment: Just wrong to copy and paste, I have others SUM in my query. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `SUM(stat=17)`, the server is going row by row looking at each `stat` column and *comparing* it with the value `17`. As long as neither of the values being compared in a comparison is `NULL`, the result will be a `1` (TRUE) or `0` (FALSE). For example, `1 > 3` evaluates to `0`.

So, `SUM(stat=17)` is adding up a bunch of ones and zeroes. The ones are contributed from the rows that have a value of 17 for column `stat` and the zeroes come from all the other rows. This ends up just counting the number of rows that have 17 in the `stat` columns. But it is a very indirect way of getting that result compared to:

```
SELECT
dateinsert, COUNT(*) as first_status
FROM my_table
WHERE dateinsert >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' and stat IN(17, 19)
GROUP BY datainsert
```

Comment: in your query you used where, but I need to SUM other fields, example 
 SUM(stat=17)+SUM(stat=19) AS first_status, SUM(stat=51)+SUM(stat=77) AS second_status... etc..

Comment: sorry you're absolutely right, my example wasn't accurate